# Find equals value into an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

There is a faster way to find equals value into an array instead of comparing all elements one by one with all the array's elements ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i ++)
{
    for(int k = i; k < arrayLenght; i ++)
    {
        if(array[i] == array[k])
        {
            sprintf(message,"There is a duplicate of %s",array[i]);
            ShowMessage(message);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you sort it first and filter out contiguous duplicates then?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a nice solution. Thank you

Comment: Or use a temporary std::set (or std::unordered_map) for existence check. Will be faster but will use more memory then sorting (unless sorting in place is not intended in which case will use similar amount of memory).

Comment: @freakish, be careful, as if you use a sorted set, then you don't get faster, as you have to include the `std::set` access time (which is **O(log(n))**)

Comment: @LuisColorado ah, i thought sets are o(1). I guess you never stop learning. :) Std::unordered_map then.

Comment: @freakish, well, it depends.  they are **O(1)** if implemented as hash sets or as bitsets.  But `std::set` is implemented as a sorted set, or what is the same as an AVL tree, internally.  Then, you have **O(log(n))**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::multiset` and then count duplicates afterwards like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    const int arrayLenght = 14;
    int array[arrayLenght] = { 0,2,1,3,1,4,5,5,5,2,2,3,5,5 };

    std::multiset<int> ms(array, array + arrayLenght);

    for (auto it = ms.begin(), end = ms.end(); it != end; it = ms.equal_range(*it).second)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        if ((cnt = ms.count(*it)) > 1)
            std::cout << "There are " << cnt << " of " << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/6ktW89

```
There are 2 of 1
There are 3 of 2
There are 2 of 3
There are 5 of 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Since sorting your container is a possible solution, [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) is the simplest solution to your problem:

```
std::vector<int> v {0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3};
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
v.erase(std::unique(begin(v), end(v)), end(v));
```

First, the vector is sorted. You can use anything, `std::sort` is just the simplest. After that, `std::unique` shifts the duplicates to the end of the container and returns an iterator to the first duplicate. This is then eaten by `erase` and effectively removes those from the vector.

Comment: `std::unique` goes back to C++98, no? Or do you mean it's the simplest solution as of C++17...

Comment: Nice solution, but I can't use vectors

Comment: `v.erase(std::unique(begin(v), end(v), end(v));` has grammar error.

Comment: @A.Ortogni if you are using C-style arrays, you cannot change their size. Just call `unique` to shift the duplicates to the end of your array and mark them as "deleted", whatever sense it could have in your situation.

Comment: @A.Ortogni You can't use one of the most fundamental data structures in C++? Wat? Is that a homework?

Comment: @freakish No, it is for work, my boss told me to not use vectors in this case

Comment: You're assuming that the value_type of array could be sorted by `<`,however,the he does not say that element has a strict weak order.

Comment: @bigxiao You should write a complementary answer ;)

Comment: @A.Ortogni -- Many STL algorithm functions work with regular arrays also.  The function `std::unique` just move items to the end of the array, and return to you where the start of these moved items are.  Of course you can't erase them in an array since an array cannot be resized, but you can move the items to the end and have the function report to you where the moved items start, and this is what `std::unique` does.

Answer (score 1):

If your `value_type` of this array could be sorted by `operator <`(a strict weak order) it's a good choice to do as YSC answered.

If not,maybe you can try to define a hash function to hash the objects to different values.Then you can do this in `O(n)` time complexity,like:

```
struct ValueHash
{
    size_t operator()(const Value& rhs) const{
        //do_something
    }
};
struct ValueCmp
{
    bool operator()(const Value& lhs, const Value& rhs) const{
          //do_something
    }
};
unordered_set<Value,ValueHash,ValueCmp> myset;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i ++)
{
    if(myset.find(array[i])==myset.end())
          myset.insert(array[i]);
    else
         dosomething();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that answer diversity is a good thing on stack overflow ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a large amount of data, you can first sort the array (quick sort gives you a first pass in **O(n*log(n)))** and then do a second pass by comparing each value with the next (as they might be all together) to find duplicates (this is a sequential pass in **O(n)**) so, sorting in a first pass and searching the sorted array for duplicates gives you **O(n*log(n) + n)**, or finally **O(n*log(n))**.

## EDIT

An alternative has been suggested in the comments, of using a `std::set` to check for *already processed* data.  The algorithm just goes element by element, checking if the element has been seen before.  This can lead to a **O(n)** algorithm, *but only if you take care of using a hash set*.  In case you use a sorted set, then you incur in an **O(log(n))** for each set search and finish in the same **O(n*log(n))**.  But because the proposal can be solved with a hash set (you have to be careful in selecting an `std::unsorted_set`, so you don't get the extra access time per search) you get a final **O(n)**.  Of course, you have to account for possible automatic hash table grow or a huge waste of memory used in the hash table.

Thanks to @freakish, who pointed the set solution in the comments to the question.